# Как сделать так, чтобы __DIR__, вызываемый в подключаемом файле, выводил путь до основного файла?

Tags: php, структуры-данных

Есть файл index.php:

```
echo __DIR__;
```

И есть файл index2.php, который находится на директорию ниже (т.е. /dir/index2.php):

```
require_once 'dir/index.php';
```

Если открыть index.php, то выведется /dir/ (т.е. директория, где лежит index2.php)

Как сделать так, чтобы выводился путь именно до index.php (/)

Comment: Для чего это нужно?

Comment: Есть один такой файл index.php и в директории dir много поддиректорий, каждая из которых содержит идентичные файлы index1.php, которые должны выводить путь до директории, в которой лежат

Comment: путь до директории, в которой лежит файл - это и есть `__DIR__`

Comment: Что-то вы не договариваете. Если `index.php` лежит в корне, то почему вы его ищете в подкаталоге `require_once 'dir/index/php';`?

Comment: ох прошу прощения, там dir/index.php

Comment: **Для чего это нужно?** Для чего нужно выводить "путь до директории"?

Comment: На реальном веб-срвере никогда не выведется  /dir/ - путь на диске всегда длинее, чем на веб-сервере. Что в итоге нужно получить и зачем?

Comment: Создайте файл main_menu.php, в котором будет содержаться массив с описанием пунктов меню, каждый пункт — это ассоциативный массив вида: array (‘title’ => название раздела, ‘path’ => url-путь к разделу, ‘sort’ => сортировка вывода).
Необходимо заполнить этот массив минимум 5 разделами. Названия и сортировка — произвольные. Путь к разделам произвольный относительно раздела route (т.е. все URL должны начинаться с /route/#ваш_раздел#/, например /route/about/ или /route/kak_kupit_kursy/).

Comment: Создайте все разделы, который вы завели в массиве меню, относительно раздела /route/ и создайте в них индексные страницы.
Дальше необходимо реализовать отдельную функцию, которая будет на созданных страницах отображать название раздела в теге <h1>.

задание на курсе